Where should the $\leq$ go in the definition of the hazard function?
I have come across two definitions of the hazard function in several textbooks and online resource.
Definition 1. Here for example.
$$h(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}\dfrac{P(t < T  \leq t + \epsilon \mid T > t)}{\epsilon},$$
Definition 2. Here for example.
$$h(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}\dfrac{P(t \leq T  < t + \epsilon \mid T \geq t)}{\epsilon}.$$
I presume if $T$ is absolutely continuous, they are equivalent. But, are there cases where they differ? If so, which one is correct?

Hazard is asking a question about hazard :)

Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please edit the question to provide an example of a reference for each definition? That might provide more context for other visitors to this site. This question uses even a different definition.

Under the hood, you are questioning two different definitions of (cumulative) distribution functions.  See this post for a in-depth discussion.

@Zhanxiong Thanks, the additional points in that post are useful.

The first definition is simpler
We often want to frame results in terms of the CDF $F$ and/or the survival function $S$ defined by:
$$F(t) \equiv \mathbb{P}(T \leqslant t)
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
S(t) \equiv \mathbb{P}(T > t).$$
If we use the first definition for the hazard function then this makes it simpler to frame things in terms of these standard objects.  In particular, we have:
$$\mathbb{P}(t < T  \leq t + \epsilon \mid T > t) 
= \frac{F(t+\epsilon)-F(t)}{1-F(t)}
= \frac{S(t)-S(t+\epsilon)}{S(t)},$$
which then gives:
$$h(t) 
= \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{F(t+\epsilon)-F(t)}{\epsilon(1-F(t))}
= \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{S(t)-S(t+\epsilon)}{\epsilon S(t)}.$$
The second defintion alters these formulae slightly, by adding/removing probabilities of individual points.  As you point out, in cases where the random variable is continuous there is no difference between the two definitions because the probability of an individual point is zero.  Cases where you get a different hazard from the two definitions only occur at "jump points" in the CDF in which case the hazard rate is either undefined or it can be considered as a multiple of the Dirac delta function (representing the derivative of the "jump").
(Note also that the first definition is simpler only because of our convention of how we define the strictness of inequality in the CDF and survival function.  If we were to have defined these using the opposite strictness then the second definition of the hazard function would be a simpler function of those objects.)

In cases where they differ the hazard rate is not defined: the numerator does not go to zero as the denominator goes to zero.
The cumulative hazard increment at a point where there is non-zero mass is $dH(t)= P(T=t|P\geq t)$, which is like the second definition.
